# jQuery - Edit content of element within parent of parent

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have multiple `<div>`'s within a `<div>`.
Within one of the child `<div>`'s is a `<select>` which I know the ID of.

I need to change the content a child `<div>` which I know the class name of:

```
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="alwaysthesame">I want to edit this content</div>
  <div>
    <select id="id1"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are multiple of the above on the same page, so I can't reference the element by class, I have to do it relative to the `<select>`

Something like:

```
$("#id1").parent().something(".alwaysthesame").html("new value");
```

Comment: @connexo closest with look for parent `alwaysthesame` is prev of parent of the select it wont work

Comment: True. I'd have expected `closest()` to work more intelligently.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#id1").parent().prev(".alwaysthesame").html("new value");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="alwaysthesame">I want to edit this content</div>
  <div>
    <select id="id1"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use `.prev()` to get the previous element which is the div you want to target

Comment: Note that this solutions depends 100% on the markup not being changed structurally.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("#id").parents("your selector goes here")`
for an example

```
$("#id").parents(".my-block")
```

this will return collection of parent elements with class my block, if you want only the first one add `.first().`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$("#id1").parent().parent().find(".alwaysthesame").html("new value");
```

Comment: there are multiple div with class `alwaysthesame`

Comment: This is awful way of doing it, what if I will have parent 3 containers above?
.parent().parent().parent() is bit messy

Comment: In That case you need a specific parent selector where you can select any Element like

$("#id1").parents('selector').find(".alwaysthesame").html("new value");

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#question').parent('div').prev('div').html('Your text')
```

Please don't forget to add Jquery reference

Answer (score 0):

The div with class `.alwaysthesame` is a sibling of `id1` parent so you could use `parent()` and `siblings` like :

```
$("#id1").parent().siblings(".alwaysthesame").html("new value");
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#id1").parent().siblings(".alwaysthesame").html("new value");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="alwaysthesame">I want to edit this content</div>
  <div>
    <select id="id1">
         <option>1</option>
         <option>2</option>
         <option>3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The safest - and most resilient way regarding future structural markup changes - would be to add a class on each of those blocks, then use `closest()` to find that element, then go for `find(".alwaysthesame")`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#id1").closest(".block").find(".alwaysthesame").text("new text");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="alwaysthesame">I want to edit this content</div>
  <div>
    <select id="id1"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

> https://api.jquery.com/closest/
>
> https://api.jquery.com/find/